# Why modification in file shows Access Denied?

Tags: java, jsp

I am changing the port number of Tomcat Server from `server.xml` file stored in config folder. 
But when I save it, it shows a message Access Denied. 
I tried to change the security settings from properties of that file but it does not work.
How to change the port number?

Comment: is your tomcat still running if you change the file?

Comment: problem is solved....  i copy the file outside the C drive and made the changes then i copy back at its old location and replace the old file.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Stop Tomcat
- start the editor as admin

might help